# Dynamically Create UI Components through Actionbuttons to Filter Dataset

Tags: r, shiny, module

**UPDATED with Limey's suggestion**

I have created a simple reproducible app in which I am attempting to add UI components through an action button so that I can filter the same dataset by the UI filters generated from the action button. The issue I am not understanding, is how to get the modularized code to save the dataset after the filter is applied to it and reuse the filtered dataset the next time the actionbutton is clicked. In other words, I want to reuse this filtered dataset (not the original unfiltered dataset) everytime a new set of UI components are generated by clicking the actionbutton. The below code launches properly, but does not perform the desired function. The error that I am getting which I cannot resolve is when I uncomment out the commented out 2 lines of code.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

add.filter.UI = function(id) {
  
  ns = NS(id)
  
  fluidRow(
    column(4, uiOutput(ns("UI_1"))),
    column(6, uiOutput(ns("UI_2"))),
    column(width = 2,
           actionButton(inputId = ns("rm.filter"), label = "Filter", icon = icon("minus"), style = "position: relative; bottom: 0; right:0; top:24px;")),
    br(),
    column(width = 12, tableOutput(ns("test"))))
  
}

add.filter.server = function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    ns = session$ns
    
    output$UI_1 <- renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = ns("sel.col"),
                  label = "Select a column",
                  choices =  names(data %>% select_if(is.numeric)),
                  multiple = F)
    })
    
    col.rng = reactive({ data %>% select(one_of(input$sel.col)) })
    
    output$UI_2 = renderUI({
      
      sliderInput(inputId = ns("sel.rng"),
                  label = "Filter the range",
                  min = min(col.rng(), na.rm = T),
                  max = max(col.rng(), na.rm = T),
                  value = c(min(col.rng(), na.rm = T), max(col.rng(), na.rm = T)),
                  step = (max(col.rng(), na.rm = T) - min(col.rng(), na.rm = T)) / 100 # of breaks
      )
    })
    
    data.filtered = reactive({
      
      data %>%
        rename(Var = one_of(input$sel.col)) %>%
        arrange(Var) %>%
        filter(Var >= min(input$sel.rng), Var <= max(input$sel.rng)) %>%
        rename(!!input$sel.col := Var) 
      
    })
    
    output$test = renderTable({
      
      data.filtered() %>%
        head()
      
    })
    
    return( data.filtered )  
    
  })
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      column(width = 2, offset = 10, actionButton(inputId = "add.filter", label = "Filter", icon = icon("plus"), style = "position:relative; left:10px;")),
      tags$div(id = 'placeholder')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput(outputId = "tbl")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df.filtered = reactiveVal(value =  mtcars )
  
  observeEvent(input$add.filter, {
    
    id <- paste0("#filter_", input$add.filter)  # - 1, "-break"
    
    insertUI(selector = "#placeholder",
             where = "afterEnd",
             ui = tags$div(
               add.filter.UI(paste0("filter_", input$add.filter)),
               id = id)
    )
    
    new.df = add.filter.server(id = paste0("filter_", input$add.filter), data = df.filtered())

    # df.filtered(new.df())  # this causes an error
    
    output$tbl = renderTable({

      new.df() 
      
      # df.filtered() # replacing the new.df() line with this line causes an error

    })
    
  })
  
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The module server should return a *reactive* ( ie `data.filtered`), not the *value of a reactive* ( ie `data.filtered()`). Does making that change solve the problem?

Comment: @Limey Ah yes it does, thank you! Now I still need to figure out why the output$tbl doesn't register every sequential UI component filter that is added by the actionbutton aside the first UI components. Any tips for this part?